# ASP.NET MVC Razor cannot find views in area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

URLs work correctly

Actions work correctly

the only problem is that the razor engine is just searching for view files in `~/Views` and not in `~/Areas/Admin` and I don't know why is that because it used to work fine

It works when I fill the return view type of the action by the exact path of its view but the absolute path for views is not working


[image: Admin Area Directory]

Here is one action for example but none of the actions in the admin area can call their views

Even `_Logout` which is a partial view ib `Shared` cannot be called by `_Layout` unless using the full path

Action in Controller:

```
        // GET: Admin/Login
        [Route("Admin/Login")]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Error:

```
The view 'Login' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Default/Login.aspx
~/Views/Default/Login.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx
~/Views/Default/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Default/Login.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml
```

Comment: Did you call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` in your `RegisterRoutes()` method?

Comment: You should look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624566/mvc-areas-view-not-found

Comment: @haim770 Sure did

Comment: @codelover Not helping

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

`[RouteArea("Admin", AreaPrefix = "")]`
Was missing from top of my controller